# Hibernate + Tomcat org/hibernate/exception/SQLGrammarException java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: web-services, hibernate, tomcat, maven, axis

Hi I'm trying to make application which will use webservice deployed on tomcat/axis2 to make some MySQL query and get for example user.

It's all working fine until I connected my project with hibernate and database. When I make sql query without tomcat it's all works. But when I deployed webservice I got this error when calling webservice:

```
[ERROR] org/hibernate/exception/SQLGrammarException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/exception/SQLGrammarException
    at org.mathew.ws.MyService.getUser(MyService.java:10)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Not found : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.findClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:96)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 30 more
```

anybody have idea why ??

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carpool</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="org.mathew.data.User"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and file pom.xml with maven dependencies:

```
<!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.GA</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- JAX-RS -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I will be really thankfull if anybody can help :).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're having problems with mis-matched jars because you're specifying too many dependencies.

You only need this Hibernate dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

The rest of the dependencies will be pulled in transitively.

Comment: so which dependencies should I remove ?? Could you specify ? When I remove other hibernate dependencies I got errors in my project.

Comment: You can remove everything which Hibernate pulls in transitively. hibernate-annotations, hibernate-commons-annotations, javassist, jta, dom4j. Just remove everything expect for hibernate-core and see what it brings back. Then remove those dependencies from your pom.

Comment: Also you have cglib in there twice? It probably won't cause you many problems. But it suggests you need to have a tidy up of your project dependencies!

Comment: I edited my question with my new pom.xml, removed all hibernate dependencies except hibernate-core but unfornately it caused the same error :(.

Comment: Alex's advice is good in general but I don't think it's related to your current issue. I do believe you have a jar conflict, but it's not because you import your hibernate jars individually (since it all works outside Tomcat). Make sure you have a clean Tomcat, with no extra jars added to it. Also look at your maven dependency hierarchy (best way to do is via m2 eclipse plugin -> dependency hierarchy) and see which transitive dependencies exist multiple times, then exclude the older versions until only one remains for each one.